# What is $P$ and $X$ is supposed to be in this analysis question?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

> [image]
>   [image]

Source [page 626](http://www.math.byu.edu/~klkuttle/lecturenotes641.pdf).

1. Can someone explain what is $\| P\| $ mean? Is that partition or what?
2. Also why bother with $\epsilon/2$ if the giant expression in the middle proves the lemma.
3. Finally, what is $X$? None of the preceding lemmas indicated what $X$ is here. Does he mean $K$? Does he also mean that

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{M} \frac{A_k}{w_k - z} = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\sum_{k=1}^{p}\sum_{j = 1}^{n} \frac{f(\gamma(t_j))(\gamma_k(t_j) - \gamma_k(t_{j-1})}{\gamma_k(t_j) - z}$$

Answer (score 1):

||P|| here seems to be the partition norm, the maximum length of a subinterval (notice the max exists for compact intervals), but I don't know what $X$ may represent.

Answer (score 1):

1. $\|P\|$ is the **norm** of partition, i.e., the maximal diameter of any set in partition.
2. Yes, $\epsilon/2$ could just as well be $\epsilon$. You're right that once we have the giant formula in the middle, the game is over. You are also correct in that 
   $$\sum_{k = 1}^{M} \frac{A_k}{w_k - z} $$ is just a neat notation for $$ \frac{1}{2\pi i}\sum_{k=1}^{p}\sum_{j = 1}^{n} \frac{f(\gamma(t_j))(\gamma_k(t_j) - \gamma_k(t_{j-1})}{\gamma_k(t_j) - z}$$
3. At the beginning of the chapter the author remarks "All these theorems work for $f$ having values in a complex Banach space." Here, he again points out that instead of $\mathbb{C}$, the map $f$ could take values in a Banach space $X$. The argument is the same, except $A_k$ are elements of $X$ instead of complex numbers. If you're not interested in the Banach space case, ignore the remark.

Comment: may i ask why is $g(w,z)$ uniformly continuous?

Comment: Usual reason: it's a continuous function on a compact set.

Comment: Oh right because $\gamma$ are closed and bounded

Comment: Oh man I hpe u stick around for a another hour because i some more questions (about to post) lol

Comment: Might I also ask why $g$ being uniform continuous implies the $\delta$ business?